# How to display Custom Validation error message using "app-form-group-control-validation-display" in angular 4

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-directive, formgroups

We are using FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl to check and display validations. For date validation I have used Custom validation. For this I have created a validation directive DateTypeValidationDirective. Please see the below code snippet.

```
import { Directive, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";
import * as moment from "moment";

@Directive({
    selector: '[date]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting:
                DateTypeValidatorDirective, multi: true }]

})

export class DateTypeValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input() dDate: Date;
    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        return this.dDate ? this.dateTypeValidator()(control)
            : null;
    }
    dateTypeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
            const valid = control.value == '' || moment(moment(control.value).format("l LT"), ["l LT"], true).isValid() 

            if (!valid) {
                return {
                      'dateType': { value: "invalid date" }
                }; 
            }    
         };
   }
}
```

In component I have used the below code snippet

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.formGroupCore = this.formBuilder.group({

     dueDate: new FormControl("", 
     [this.dateTypeValidatorDirective.dateTypeValidator()])
    });
}
```

In html file written the below code

```
<input id="dueDate" type="date" formControlName="dueDate" 
            class="form-control form-control-sm" />

<app-form-group-control-validation-display
    *ngIf="formGroupCore.get('dueDate').hasError(error)" 
    [formGroup]="formGroupCore" [propertyName]="'dueDate'" >invalid date
</app-form-group-control-validation-display>
```

The validation is working fine but error message is not displaying. How to set the error message?

Please anyone help to achieve the same

Comment: I think must be formGroupCore.get('dueDate').hasError('dateType')

Comment: Elseo how to write the code?

Comment: I've edited your question because I can't see the html code. (but I don't changed any comma of your question) Tip: in a question, select the lines of codes and press Ctrl+K to format the code

Comment: Eliseo actually formGroupCore.get('dueDate').hasError('dateType') is working. Can you please tell how to display the message in app-form-group-control-validation-display?

Comment: try formGroupCore.get('dueDate').getError('dateType') -but I'm not sure-. Anyway, see the documentation: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#abstractcontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with the below code snippet and the validation works fine.

```html
<app-form-group-control-validation-display  [formGroup]="formGroupCore" [propertyName]="'dueDate'" [custom]="[{'dateType':'Please enter a valid date'}]">
                            </app-form-group-control-validation-display>
```